# asp:login not working (no changes made)

Tags: asp.net, authentication

so I have a login page that's pretty standard:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="NotLoggedIn.ascx.cs" Inherits="CodePerfect.LicenceManager.AccountManagement.Controls.CustomErrors.InsufficientPermissions.NotLoggedIn" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="vctrl" Namespace="ServerControls.ValidatedControls.TextBox" Assembly="ServerControls" %>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Resources/css/NewHome.css" />

<script type="text/javascript">

    masterApp.controller("homePageCtrl", [
        "$scope", function ($scope) {
            //        $scope.windowOptions = {
            //            appendTo: '#form1',
            //        }
        }
    ]);

</script>

<style>
    #SettingsBar {
        width: 50px !important;
    }
    .row{
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>


<div id="home" data-ng-controller="homePageCtrl">
    <%--    <div class="holder">
        <div id="phone" class="phone"><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;01202 636592</div>
    </div>--%>
    <div id="logo">
        <i class="fa fa-users"></i>&nbsp;System Manager
    </div>


    <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server"
        CssClass="LoginControl">
        <LayoutTemplate>

            <div class="logintemp">
                <div class="row">
                <div style="width: 50%; position: relative; float: left;">
                    <label>User Name:</label>
                    <div class="rowform">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" CssClass="k-textBox"></asp:TextBox>

                    </div>
                    <div class="checkholder">
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server"
                            ControlToValidate="UserName" ErrorMessage="User Name is required."
                            ToolTip="User Name is required." ValidationGroup="Login1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style="width: 49%; position: relative; float: left;">
                    <label>Password:</label>
                    <div class="rowform">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password" CssClass="k-textBox"></asp:TextBox>

                    </div>
                    <div class="checkholder">
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server"
                            ControlToValidate="Password" ErrorMessage="Password is required."
                            ToolTip="Password is required." ValidationGroup="Login1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" CommandName="Login" Text="Log In" CssClass="k-button loginButton"
                        ValidationGroup="Login1" />
                </div>

            </div>
        </LayoutTemplate>
    </asp:Login>





</div>
```

I am making changes to the site but no where near the login page.  I had the same issue yesterday so I turned on logging for the UAT site (this site), but then it magically started working.

Same issue today.  I made some changes far, far away from any login process and suddenly the login stopped working.  The logs that I turned on tell me nothing (last activity below):

Any idea what could be wrong, or even how I can start debugging the issue?

There is no code behind this page or the control

Thanks ^_^
Andy

> 2017-03-24 10:03:21 W3SVC45 xx.xx.xx.xx GET /signalr/connect
>   transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=y%2B72zAe%2B%2BpxHean7FKeyR%2FbdnoCs3d83RySonpwctt%2BnXqoYPDhSwCUA1ZxfWjznekWxAlxfiyhJVmQEsV84RgCc3Ne6BUzrbEhs44fALgaq4AWwL3obVSW1vJ1I13P1&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22accountmanagerhub%22%7D%5D&tid=6
>   443 - xx.xx.xx.xx
>   Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/56.0.2924.87+Safari/537.36
>   - 101 0 0 439247 2017-03-24 10:03:21 W3SVC45 xx.xx.xx.xx GET / - 443 - xx.xx.xx.xx
>   Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/56.0.2924.87+Safari/537.36
>   - 200 0 0 93 2017-03-24 10:03:21 W3SVC45 xx.xx.xx.xx POST /signalr/abort
>   transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=y%2B72zAe%2B%2BpxHean7FKeyR%2FbdnoCs3d83RySonpwctt%2BnXqoYPDhSwCUA1ZxfWjznekWxAlxfiyhJVmQEsV84RgCc3Ne6BUzrbEhs44fALgaq4AWwL3obVSW1vJ1I13P1&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22accountmanagerhub%22%7D%5D
>   443 - xx.xx.xx.xx
>   Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/56.0.2924.87+Safari/537.36
>   https://uatsystemmanager.eb-d.uk/ 200 0 0 78 2017-03-24 10:03:22
>   W3SVC45 xx.xx.xx.xx GET /signalr/hubs - 443 - 81.133.199.221
>   Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/56.0.2924.87+Safari/537.36
>   https://uatsystemmanager.eb-d.uk/ 200 0 0 127 2017-03-24 10:03:22
>   W3SVC45 xx.xx.xx.xx GET /signalr/negotiate
>   clientProtocol=1.5&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22accountmanagerhub%22%7D%5D&*=1490349789330
>   443 - xx.xx.xx.xx
>   Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/56.0.2924.87+Safari/537.36
>   https://uatsystemmanager.eb-d.uk/ 200 0 0 15 2017-03-24 10:03:22
>   W3SVC45 xx.xx.xx.xx GET /Resources/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2
>   v=4.5.0 443 - xx.xx.xx.xx
>   Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/56.0.2924.87+Safari/537.36
>   https://uatsystemmanager.eb-d.uk/Resources/css/font-awesome.css 404 3
>   50 109 2017-03-24 10:03:23 W3SVC45 xx.xx.xx.xx GET /signalr/start
>   transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=UX9hkD%2Fb9mNhp6hyMTAOfBCXcEbduyKK4RsBV4X3%2BbIzLZC31hhvxRiWaU6MGHsi3381G7qUVuAXKf9z8rr0To5iHtzbFudUvimHBoyPTpHgPStSmP2iYgf1%2BGO2ar%2Bk&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22accountmanagerhub%22%7D%5D&*=1490349789331
>   443 - xx.xx.xx.xx
>   Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/56.0.2924.87+Safari/537.36
>   https://uatsystemmanager.eb-d.uk/ 200 0 0 31 2017-03-24 10:03:24
>   W3SVC45 xx.xx.xx.xx POST / - 443 - xx.xx.xx.xx
>   Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/56.0.2924.87+Safari/537.36
>   https://uatsystemmanager.eb-d.uk/ 200 0 0 62 2017-03-24 10:03:24
>   W3SVC45 xx.xx.xx.xx GET /signalr/connect
>   transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=UX9hkD%2Fb9mNhp6hyMTAOfBCXcEbduyKK4RsBV4X3%2BbIzLZC31hhvxRiWaU6MGHsi3381G7qUVuAXKf9z8rr0To5iHtzbFudUvimHBoyPTpHgPStSmP2iYgf1%2BGO2ar%2Bk&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22accountmanagerhub%22%7D%5D&tid=0
>   443 - xx.xx.xx.xx
>   Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/56.0.2924.87+Safari/537.36
>   - 101 0 0 2062 2017-03-24 10:03:24 W3SVC45 xx.xx.xx.xx POST /signalr/abort
>   transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=UX9hkD%2Fb9mNhp6hyMTAOfBCXcEbduyKK4RsBV4X3%2BbIzLZC31hhvxRiWaU6MGHsi3381G7qUVuAXKf9z8rr0To5iHtzbFudUvimHBoyPTpHgPStSmP2iYgf1%2BGO2ar%2Bk&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22accountmanagerhub%22%7D%5D
>   443 - xx.xx.xx.xx
>   Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/56.0.2924.87+Safari/537.36
>   https://uatsystemmanager.eb-d.uk/ 200 0 0 78 2017-03-24 10:03:24
>   W3SVC45 xx.xx.xx.xx GET /signalr/hubs - 443 - xx.xx.xx.xx
>   Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/56.0.2924.87+Safari/537.36
>   https://uatsystemmanager.eb-d.uk/ 200 0 0 31 2017-03-24 10:03:25
>   W3SVC45 xx.xx.xx.xx GET /signalr/negotiate
>   clientProtocol=1.5&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22accountmanagerhub%22%7D%5D&*=1490349792380
>   443 - xx.xx.xx.xx
>   Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/56.0.2924.87+Safari/537.36
>   https://uatsystemmanager.eb-d.uk/ 200 0 0 15 2017-03-24 10:03:25
>   W3SVC45 xx.xx.xx.xx GET /Resources/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2
>   v=4.5.0 443 - xx.xx.xx.xx
>   Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/56.0.2924.87+Safari/537.36
>   https://uatsystemmanager.eb-d.uk/Resources/css/font-awesome.css 404 3
>   50 31 2017-03-24 10:03:25 W3SVC45 xx.xx.xx.xx GET /signalr/start
>   transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=60gOq9uRZSloVYFHv%2FJeUzPndWRFDsqtxPXTjiywRk2qS%2FdBpNqsTjhhsoaP10z1VzD80mBYPO27xNkEGuQLY8VaD47iEj1i35Lkwsft%2Bfs%2BgHljDG4zSyeJVPueLBfz&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22accountmanagerhub%22%7D%5D&*=1490349792381
>   443 - xx.xx.xx.xx
>   Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/56.0.2924.87+Safari/537.36
>   https://uatsystemmanager.eb-d.uk/ 200 0 0 15

Answer (score 0):

Never mind.  deleted the whole thing and did another clean publish (just as I did this morning) and it started working again.

GAH I wish I knew what the cause was >_<